# How to change ListView Item's background when onLongClick if adapter extends CursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have ListView which gets data from SQLite and a Cursor Adapter.

**How I am going to change the ListView Item background when I longclick on it?**

I implemented the following in my adapter

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v)
{


    return true;
}
```

and I have this in my Activity

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (mActionMode != null) {
                return false;
            }

            mActionMode = TActivity.this.startActionMode(TActivity.this);
            view.setSelected(true);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

but I am rather confused about the next steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like

```
if (mActionMode != null)
            {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                mActionMode.finish();
                return false;
            }else
            {
                mActionMode = Tctivity.this.startActionMode(TActivity.this);
                view.setSelected(true);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b8dbd3"));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if (mActionMode != null) {
            return false;
        }

        mActionMode = TActivity.this.startActionMode(TActivity.this);
        view.setSelected(true);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes but in this way is always selected what happens if we deselect it?